# Xcode: attaching physics bodies to nodes in the .sks file editor, as don in sample code called "Adventure"

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to understand how walls are placed in the .sks file for the swift version of apple's sample code Adventure Game. In the .sks file they are able to give an empty node called "wall", a physics body that appears as a green rectangle.

The sample code :   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Adventure-Swift/Introduction/Intro.html

However only color sprites objects have the option in the node inspector of adding a physics body.

How are physics bodies attached to empty nodes in the .sks file.

What am I misunderstanding?